# Nativescript {N} oAuth plugin - Retrieve User Facebook Data

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, oauth, nativescript

## Context

I'm attempting to create an Android app with [Nativecript](https://www.nativescript.org/) using JavaScript. On the first page, it asks the user to connect with Facebook, and I intend to verify whether or not an account exists with their email address.

## Tools

I'm using the `nativescript-oauth` package to handle the OAuth connection to Facebook. I'm working on a Windows 10 machine via command line.

## Code

*app.js*

```
var tnsOAuthModule = require("nativescript-oauth");

var facebookInitOptions = TnsOAuthOptionsFacebook = {
    clientId: 'REDACTED',
    clientSecret: 'REDACTED',
    scope: ['email']
};
tnsOAuthModule.initFacebook(facebookInitOptions);

application.start({ moduleName: "views/start/start" });
```

*start.js*

```
//...
var tnsOAuthModule = require("nativescript-oauth");
//...

exports.fbConnect = function(){
    console.log("Facebook Connect button tapped");

    tnsOAuthModule.login()
        .then(()=>{
            console.log('logged in');
            var token = tnsOAuthModule.accessToken();
            console.log("FB Auth token: " + token);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(tnsOAuthModule));
        })
        .catch((er)=>{
            console.log(er);
        });

    console.log("Login sucessful");
}
```

#### What goes wrong

The above outputs the following:

```
JS: Facebook Connect button tapped
...
JS: logged in
JS: FB Auth token: EAAC50oamJosBAF1F3lrGAOntENgSAZA40w4iE3rNOLP1W_REDACTED_Cb7yS9ZB1Ro4qhLroOMwZD
JS: {"instance":{"tokenResult":{"accessToken":"EAAC50oamJosBAF1F3lrGAOntENgSAZA40w4iE3rNOLP1W_REDACTED_Cb7yS9ZB1Ro4qhLroOMwZD","accessTokenExpiration":"2017-03-24T18:27:04.176Z","refreshTokenExpiration":"2017-03-24T18:27:04.176Z"},"credentials":{"authority":"https://www.facebook.com/dialog","tokenEndpointBase":"https://graph.facebook.com","authorizeEndpoint":"/oauth","tokenEndpoint":"/v2.3/oauth/access_token","clientId":"REDACTED","clientSecret":"REDACTED","redirectUri":"https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html","scope":"email"}}}
JS: Application started successfully
```

As you can see, I successfully authorise the Facebook app and retrieve a working access key and can parse the object that is returned - however I'm trying to retrieve the users' email address. I can see that the "email" is within the scope.

### Question

How can I use the `nativescript-oauth` plugin, or the data from the above object, to retrieve the users' email address, as defined the in `scope`?

#### Resources

- [Nativescript homepage - https://www.nativescript.org/](https://www.nativescript.org/)
- [`nativescript-oauth` GitHub page - https://github.com/alexziskind1/nativescript-oauth](https://github.com/alexziskind1/nativescript-oauth)
- [Nativescript official release of OAuth plugin - https://www.nativescript.org/blog/introducing-the-nativescript-oauth-plugin](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/introducing-the-nativescript-oauth-plugin)

Comment: You call `/me?fields=email` to get the email of a user

Answer (score 0):

You must change the scope to get more details(add "user_friends" to get their friend's list, add "public_profile" for profile info)

```
var facebookInitOptions = TnsOAuthOptionsFacebook = {
    clientId: 'REDACTED',
    clientSecret: 'REDACTED',
    scope: ['email', 'user_friends', 'public_profile']
};
```

Lastly, in your "App review" section of your facebook developer page, ensure those scope fields are active and shown(they will have a green dot next to them with description of data). You might need to make the app live/start a submission to get approval first if the above code doesn't work.